# Microsoft Excel Formula to fill a range of cells

Tags: excel

I'm working on a project that will assist in our design department. I came across an issue, which I have spent almost a week on without much success.

Let's say I have the following values in A1 and A2 :

- A1 = 4
- A2 = 3

Final result:
[image]

I have tried many formulas, but none can give the result I desire, from If-Array, etc and I am out of ideas.

Any assistance will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you,
Steven

Comment: Can you be more specific about the logic for values in the cells? Just looking at the final result it's not clear at all...

Comment: No clarity in your question

Comment: Maybe `=IF(COLUMN()<=$A$1,1,IF(COLUMN()<=$A$1+$A$2,2))`in `A5` then copy to right.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you see that in the first cell there is the value 4, and in the second cell (underneath it), you have the value 3. So you want to select a cell (A5 in this case), and you want to put 4 times the value "1", and afterwards you want to put 3 times the value "2". You mention you want to do this with a formula, but in my opinion it's much more easy to write a small macro for this, or is this not an option for you?

Comment: The values 4 and 3 is the result from other formulas. This will be a layout design for a tank, where for example, the cells with a 1 will be an upright panel and cells with 2 will be the floor. It very important to see the flat layout because it is easier to determine bracing on the inside of the tank when you see it in flat view. Values in A1 and A2 is tank size. conditional formatting will then be used to color the cells based on their values (1,2,3,4,etc)

Comment: Hi Axel, Tried your example and it worked. Thank you very much. Can you maybe explain how this works. Understanding the solution will be really nice. Also, lets say I want to move the formula to a different part of the work sheet, how will that affect the column counting?

Comment: Hi Axel, Never-mind the second part of my comment, figured out how the formula works, awesome. I see light in the tunnel. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(COLUMN()<=$A$1,1,IF(COLUMN()<=$A$1+$A$2,2))
```

In A5 then copy to right.

(as per comments)